# Dynamically Change Concurrent Consumers - rabbitMQ

Tags: spring-rabbit

I am using SimpleRabbitListenerFactory and am trying to dynamically decrease/increase the concurrentConsumers which am not able to achieve. Can anybody help me with this. Thank you

Code is as follows:

```
SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory factory;
@Bean
public SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory rabbitListenerContainerFactory()
{
 factory=new SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory();
 factory.setConnectionFactory(this.connectionFactory);
 changeConsumers(2);
 return factory;
}

public void changeConsumers(int minConsumers)
{
 factory.setConcurrentConsumers(2);
}


***In another package***


if(messageCount>6000)
  changeConsumers(5);
```

When message count is morethan 6000 it is going into the changeCOnsumers method but consumers are not changing to 5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The factory is used during application initialization to create listener container objects; changing its properties later won't change the properties on containers it has already created.

You have to change the property on the containers themselves.

You can access the containers using the `RabbitListenerEndpointRegistry` bean; call `getListenerContainers` and iterate over them (or get an individual container using it's `id`).

Cast the `MessageListenerContainer` to `SimpleMessageListenerContainer` to change its properties.